# 50's story: space travelers reach speed of light, universe implodes

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, parallel-universe, speed-of-light

It was probably a short story by one of the popular sci-fi writers of the 50s. As I remember it, the story unfolded in a space vehicle where two travelers had embarked on a mission to exceed the speed of light in exploring the universe. Just as they reached their goal the focus shifted to what appeared to be another dimension, and two beings were viewing events in a sort of fishbowl containing our universe. They were lamenting that the contents of their fishbowl would now self destruct due to the success of those space travelers in reaching the speed of light.

The story stuck in my mind all these years, despite the fact that I moved on to many other interests in the intervening decades. I would appreciate it if anybody could identify the author and particulars of that story

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: That would be "1950s" - that was the decade during which I was an avid consumer of sci fi stories. That declined during the 1960s, with college and romance taking over my attention. I was into both magazines and anthologies, so I can't really say which

Comment: I don’t think this story had the shift of PoV, but the Randall Garrett story Time Fuze from 1954 has the element of the drive being destructive. It’s available here: http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/32347

Comment: Thanks for pointing out "Time Fuze." Good story, similar thinking to the one I was looking for, but not the one.